# Windows 7 driver search woefully slow

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update, device-manager

Any thoughts on why the driver search (when installing a usb device) on windows 7 is woefully slow? Even when I click to disable trying to get a driver from windows update, it still takes 10min+ to either find a driver, or bail out.

Is there a way to speed this up, or alternately, disable windows trying to find drivers, so I can manually install them in device manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its Windows 7, the time taken is incredibly long, especially if its set to use Windows update to scan for drivers on /every/ connect. That plus my flaky, flaky and slow Internet connection which resulted in timeouts means it took forever to detect. Asked Windows not to look at Windows update, and it was much better.